# Function is executing before it is intended to

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, synchronous

I have a web page that listens for some button clicks. One of the buttons ("generateReport") returns 1 row of data to the container and the other ("generateReporFromRange") returns a range of rows to the container. The range button is essentially just the singular one in a for loop.

I then have another function ("pBuyGauge") that pretty much creates an HTML/CSS radial gauge using an array to calculate an average. My issue is that the "myArr" array and "average" variable in the pBuyGauge function return an empty array and null value respectively, but only on the first click of the range button! If i click it again it will then calculate the values. I thought that by calling pBuyGauge at the end of the for loop in generateReportFromRange would mean that it has values in the array. But seems to calculate on its own before anything else.

```
<script>                       

export default {
  name: "pmReport",
  components: { myTable, appShell },

  data() {
    return {
      error: null,
      jobNumber: null,
      jobRangeMin: 0,
      jobRangeMax: 0,
      rowData: [],
      pBuyArr: []
    };

  },

  methods: {

    generateReportFromRange() {

      let jobIds = range(this.jobRangeMin, (this.jobRangeMax+1));

      jobIds.forEach(id => {

        this.error = "Loading..."; // show loading status in error indicator
        this.generateReport(id.toString());
        this.error = "Loading..."; // show loading status in error indicator

      });

      this.error = ""; // clear error on completion
      this.jobRangeMin = 0;
      this.jobRangeMax = 0;

      this.pBuyGauge();

    },

    generateReport(id = null) {

      fetch("/api/pm", {
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        credentials: "include",
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
          jobnum: id || this.jobNumber,
          user: this.$store.state.user
        })

      })
        .then(r =>
          r.json().then(json => {
            if (!json["Job Number"]) {
              this.error = "You do not have access to the specified record.";
              return;
            }


            this.error = "";
            this.cleanNumbers(json);
            this.columnNames(json);

            this.pBuyArr.push(parseInt(json["Percent Buy"])); //For some reason it's important this line is here and not above

            console.log("RRROp", r)

          })
        )
        .catch(e => {
          console.error("PM Fetch error", e); // eslint-disable-line
          this.error = e.message;
        });

    },

    pBuyGauge() {

      let myArr = this.pBuyArr; ////ALWAYS EMPTY FIRST TIME

      var pBuy = 0;
      var total = 0;
      var i=0;
      var average = 0;

      for(i = 0; i < (myArr.length); i++) {

          pBuy = myArr[i];
          total = total + pBuy;
      }

      average = total / myArr.length;

      console.log(JSON.stringify(myArr))
      console.log("My avg is:", JSON.stringify(average))

      var cf = 943;

      if (average >= 21) {

        var semi_cf = 0;

      }else if (average <= 0){

        var semi_cf = 707;

      }else{    

        var semi_cf = 707-(average*33.67);

      }

      document.querySelector('#mask').setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", semi_cf + "," + cf);

    }

  },
```

Comment: Right, because ajax is asynchronous.

Comment: Like Kevin said, ajax requests are asynchronous. You should wait for all `generateReport` requests to complete before executing `pBuyGauge` function. In order to do so, store all promises returned by `fetch` method, put it in an array and use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), which wait's for all promises passed as an argument to finish before calling method given in `then`.

Comment: @KevinB I honestly did not even know this was called AJAX. Kind of had this project dumped on me cause i'm the only one with some amount of programming knowledge at my company. How might I get this pBuyGauge function to wait until the function in which its called is finito?

Comment: Move it into the callback, after it does all the things it does.

Comment: @KevinB Already tried some callback stuff so I didnt post a question unnecessarily. Couldnt really figure out the syntax for it, Ill try some more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `fetch()`, which is asynchronous. It will start a request to the server in the background. In the meantime, your code continues execution, and your array will be empty by then. Somewhen in the future, the call is done and calls back, the returned Promise gets fullfilled, and the `.then` callback chained to it gets executed. Therefore the array will be filled somewhen. Now you want to wait for continuing till that point somewhere in the future. For that, first of all, collect all the promises by returning them from your promise and storing them in an array:

```
  generateReport(id = null) {
   return fetch("/api/pm", {
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    credentials: "include",
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({
      jobnum: id || this.jobNumber,
      user: this.$store.state.user
    })
  })
  .then(r => r.json())
  .then(json => {
    if (!json["Job Number"]) {
       // proper error handling involves rejecting the promise:
       throw new Error("You do not have access to the specified record.");
    }
    /*this.cleanNumbers(json);
    this.columnNames(json); Should this function really cause side effects ? */

   return parseInt(json["Percent Buy"]); // Thats what the returned promise chain resolves to
  });
 }


 //...
const promises = [];

 this.error = "Loading..."; 

jobIds.forEach(id => { 
    promises.push(this.generateReport(id.toString()));        
});
```

Now that we have an array of Promises, we can call `Promise.all` on it, which will turn the array of promises into one promise that contains the promises results:

```
  Promise.all(promises).then(result => {
    console.log(result); // << thats what you are looking for
    //... your code to work with the result
 });
```